# Regular Topology

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to find all topologies on the set $X = \{1,2,3\}$ that are $T_0$, $T_1$ and then all that are $T_3$. I believe I am good with which ones are $T_1$.

A $T_3$ or regular space is for every $x \in X$ and for every closed set $F \subseteq X$ not containing $x$ there exists open sets $U$ and $V$ which separate $\{x\}$ and $F$. I'm not sure how to apply this to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is of course but one $T_1$ topology on a finite set: the discrete topology. The discrete topology is also regular. Another obviously regular topology is the indiscrete (trivial) topology: there are no pairs of closed sets and points to separate at all, except $F= \emptyset$ and any $x$ (where we are forced to use $U = X$).

A space that is both regular and $T_0$ is $T_1$: Let $x \neq y$. Then say we have (by $T_0$) an open $O$ with $x \in O$, $y \notin O$ ("half of $T_1$-ness). Then $x \notin X\setminus O$, and the latter set is closed, so (by regularity) we have $x \in U$, $X \setminus O \subseteq V$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$ for some open $U,V$ open. Then $y \in V$ and $x \notin V$ showing the other "half" of $T_1$-ness.

So if we are looking for non-discrete regular topologies, we need to look for topologies that are not $T_0$.

Here is a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_topological_space#3_points) of all (non-homeomorphic) topologies on a three point set $\{a,b,c\}$:

1. $\{\emptyset, \{a,b,c\}\}$ (indiscrete/trivial, so trivially regular)
2. $\{\emptyset, \{c\}, \{a,b,c\}\}$ The only non-trivial closed set is $\{a,b\}$ and we cannot separate this from $c$. Not regular.
3. $\{\emptyset, \{a,b\}, \{a,b,c\}\}$ $\{c\}$ is closed and cannot be separated from $a$. Not regular.
4. $\{\emptyset, \{c\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,b,c\}\}$ regular, as all closed sets are also open.
5. $\{\emptyset, \{c\}, \{b,c\}, \{a,b,c\}\}$, $T_0$, so not regular.
6. $\{\emptyset, \{c\}, \{a,c\}, \{b,c\}, \{a,b,c\}\}$, $T_0$, so not regular.
7. $\{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,b,c\}\}$,$T_0$, so not regular.
8. $\{\emptyset, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a,b\}, \{b,c\}, \{a,b,c\}\}$ $T_0$, so not regular.
9. $\{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,c\}, \{b,c\}, \{a,b,c\}\}$ (discrete, so $T_0$ **and** regular)

This is up-to homeomorphism, through permutations of the points we get more topologies (I explain that [here](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=homework_help_2000&task=show_msg&msg=0041.0001)) but no essential new examples.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I thought I had read that to be regular, it must also be T1. By that assumption, then the discrete topology would be the only regular space. But you say there are 3 regular topologies. Am I wrong in that assumption?

Comment: @Alexba23 There are two schools of thought here: $T_3$ includes $T_1$ (which here would be boring), or $T_3$ is a synonym for "regular". The OP provided the definition. It's more interesting here to consider pure "regularity" here, because adding $T_1$ trivialises the question.